# HowTo: Query MySQL to retrieve search data, while limiting the results and sorting by a field.

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two simple Mysql tables:

```
SYMBOL
| id | symbol |  
(INT(primary) - varchar)

PRICE
| id | id_symbol | date | price |  
(INT(primary), INT(index), date, double)
```

I have to pass two symbols to get something like:

```
   DATE         A       B
2001-01-01 | 100.25 | 25.26
2001-01-02 | 100.23 | 25.25
2001-01-03 | 100.24 | 25.24
2001-01-04 | 100.25 | 25.26
2001-01-05 | 100.26 | 25.28
2001-01-06 | 100.27 | 30.29
```

Where **A** and **B** are the symbols i need to search and the **date** is the date of the prices. (because i need the *same date* to compare symbol)

If one symbol doesn't have a date that has the other I have to jump it. I only need to retrive the last N prices of those symbols.

**ORDER:** from the earliest date to latest (example the last 100 prices of both)

How could I implement this query?

Thank you

Comment: Where is the date of the price stored?

Comment: I only se one symbol column here. Is either A or B the price? And as early mentioned, where do you store the date?

Comment: ops my mistake! I added the data column to "price" table

Comment: the price table has: 1, 01/01/2011 100.25 (Where 1 is the symbol ID, 01/01/2011 the date and 100.25 the price of that date)

Answer (score 0):

Implementing these steps should bring you the desired result:

1. Get dates and prices for symbol `A`. (Inner join `PRICE` with `SYMBOL` to obtain the necessary rows.)
2. Similarly get dates and prices for symbol `B`.
3. Inner join the two result sets on the date column and pull the price from the first result set as the `A` column and the other one as `B`.

This should be simple if you know how to join tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should update your question to resolve any of the mistakes you made in representing your data. I'm having a hard time following the details. However, I think based on what I am seeing there are four MySQL concepts you need to solve your problem.

The first is JOINS you would use a join to put two tables together so you may select related data using the key that you describe as "id_symbol"

The second would be to use LIMIT which will allow you to specify the number of records to return such as that if you wanted one record you would use the keywould LIMIT 1 or if you wanted a hundred records LIMIT 100

The third would be to use a WHERE clause to allow you to search for a specific value in one of your fields from the table you are querying.

The last is the ORDER BY which will allow you to specify a field to sort your returned records and the direction you want them sorted ASC or DESC

An Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
  JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table1_id
WHERE table1.searchfield = 'search string'
LIMIT 100
ORDER BY table1.orderfield DESC
```

(This is pseudo code so this query may not actually work but is close and should provide you with the correct idea.)

I suggest referencing the MySQL documentation found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/) it should provide everything you need to keep going.